# Can't select the DOM elements inside content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to select the DOM elements using querySelector inside my content script. The script look like below.

> content.js

```js
console.log(document.body); // prints the document body
const postContainer = document.querySelector("._aabd"); // prints null
```

I can't understand why postContainer is null even the document.body has the particular class name. I'm firing the content script when all the sources are loaded completely with the help of a background script.

> background.js

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(({ tabId, url, frameId }) => {
  if (frameId !== 0 || !url.startsWith("https://www.instagram.com/")) return;
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId },
    files: ["download.js"],
  });
  chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
    target: { tabId },
    files: ["style.css"],
  });
});
```

Comment: Please see this. [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: But when I can log the whole document, the querySelector command should also work.

Comment: Use MutationObserver to detect when the element or the attribute is added. Modern sites often do it after the page has been completely loaded. Note that devtools console shows the node's new state at the time you opened the console and not the original state when the message was printed, this is how devtools works.